# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement - jQuery ContentHover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

Getting the error on console, says something is wrong with this code..

```
$.fn.contenthover = function(method) {  
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method '+ method +' does not exist in contentHover plugin.');
    }
});
```

And also this in HTML

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#d1').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#000',
        overlay_opacity:0.5
    });
});
</script>
```

Could someone tell me where I went wrong with both? Thanks! - stilllearning

Comment: What is `methods` in `methods[method]`?

Comment: Don't know really, downloaded the file from http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/

Comment: The code you supplied looks OK to me, the error must be in one of the functions that were `apply`ed defined in `methods`

Comment: _[Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue to me looks like a trailing parentheses at the end. Try this:

```
$.fn.contenthover = function(method) {  
    if (methods[method]) {
        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method '+ method +' does not exist in contentHover plugin.');
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the full error message? Can you post more code? Because running your code now in the console doesn't give any error messages other than that `methods` is undefined, but that's because it's not defined in the code you posted (though it exists in the code in the link you posted)

Comment: SyntaxError: missing } after function body contentHover.js:161

Comment: http://www.backslash.gr/demos/contenthover-jquery-plugin/ got the code from here, can you look it up there?

Comment: I ran their source code and I didn't get any errors :/

Comment: But it sounds like adding a } on line 161 or 162 in your case to close the function body would fix the issue

Comment: When I add a } it suddenly shows this: SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical contentHover.js:161

So i changed it to };} is it wrong like this? Also where should I add )?

Sorry for the thousand questions

Comment: Can you throw that file up in a jsFiddle where I can more easily take a look at it?

Comment: Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lo9trb80/1/ You can see at the end where I added the parenthesis. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

```
     $.fn.contenthover = function(method) {  
if (methods[method]) {
    return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
} else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
    return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
} else {
    $.error('Method '+ method +' does not exist in contentHover plugin.');
} 
}
```

Please Remove this **"):"** characters from the function.

Comment: from $.fn.contenthover function

Comment: Is "$.fn.contenthover " is inside script tag?